# Pipe in ternary expression in html

Tags: angular

Hy, I need some suggestion how to convert this part of code

```
<h3 mat-dialog-title>{{ user ? "Edit User" : "New User" }}</h3>
```

to use pipe inside, something like this

```
<h3 mat-dialog-title>{{ user ? {{ "EDIT_USER" | translate | async}} : {{ "NEW_USER" | translate | async}} }}</h3>
```

I know, I can use `*ngIf` or check for this directly in component, but is there any other solution to use the ternary expressions for this?

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: Use ( ) for piped expressions.

Comment: @Tushar i get this error `Parser Error: Unexpected token`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot interpolate in an interpolation and `{{ {{ }} }}` makes a problem.

Furthermore, I'd rather use parenthesis to group the whole expression to translate:

```
<h3 mat-dialog-title>
    {{ (user ?  "EDIT_USER" : "NEW_USER") | translate | async }}
</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using Interpolation in Interpolation, its not valid.
You can do like this :

```
<h3 mat-dialog-title>
{{ user ? ("EDIT_USER" | translate | async) : ( "NEW_USER" | translate | async) }}
</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<h3 mat-dialog-title>{{ user ? ("Edit User"| translate | async) : ("New User"| translate | async) }}</h3>
```